# AngularJS extend default get of $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have thin service wrapped around `$resource` to handle communication with API. Usually it works just as needed. However now I would like to extend `get` from `$resource`.

Let's say that front end need returned data in certain order. Back end for whatever reason can not be modified. Sort order will be needed application wide, so changing it in `$resource` definition would be best.

Official documentation is silent on this topic. Adding new functions is well documented, but changing default ones is not.
How to (ideally) add `.then()` to `get`.

Comment: Have you tried use `$provide.decorator` ? Anyway you wrap your method and attach $q there for example: `function wrap() { var def = $q.defer; dosmthAsync(def.resolve); return def}`

Comment: I have full controll over definition of my service and $resource used to communicate with API, though idea of wrapping function got me interested. Could I wrap `get` returned by $resource that way? Can You post that as answer?

Comment: yes. let me do that.

Comment: guys've answered already. You can try return $q.defer from transformResponse. But as i remember it returns promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your thin service wrapper looks like, but if you want to do something with your response you could use `transformResponse`-property.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
   .factory('myWrapper', function($resource){
      return function(url){
         return $resource(url,
                          {},
                          {
                           get: {method: 'GET',
                                 transformResponse: function(data, headers){
                                   data.sort() //or something
                                   return data;
                                 }
                                }
                           }
                        );
                    };

      });
```

this will override default get.

Comment: original $resource `get` definition comes down to {method: 'GET'} ? Silly me :D I was worried that its something more complex.

Comment: hehe yes, not very complex definition

Comment: notice: `data` will be a string. you need to parse it yourself depending on the format (JSON / XML) you expect.

Comment: and headers is a function that returns the headers

Answer (score 1):

The `transformResponse` option might be handy if you want to modify/sort the response.

Comment: Can You give me code snippet for adding "transformResponse" to get?